# How to use --num-executors option with spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to override spark properties such as `num-executors` while submitting the application by spark-submit as below :

```
spark-submit --class WC.WordCount \
--num-executors 8 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--executor-memory 3584M \
...../<myjar>.jar \
/public/blahblahblah /user/blahblah
```

However its running with default number of executors which is 2. But I am able to override properties if I add

```
--master yarn
```

Can someone explain why it is so ? Interestingly , in my application code I am setting master as yarn-client:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
   .setAppName("wordcount")
   .setMaster("yarn-client")
   .set("spark.ui.port","56487")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Can someone throw some light as to how the option `--master` works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am trying to override spark properties such as num-executors while submitting the application by spark-submit as below

It will **not** work (unless you override `spark.master` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file or similar so you don't have to specify it explicitly on the command line).

The reason is that the default Spark master is `local[*]` and the number of executors is exactly one, i.e. the driver. That's just the local deployment environment. See [Master URLs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls).

As a matter of fact, `num-executors` is very YARN-dependent as you can see in the help:

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --help
...
 YARN-only:
  --num-executors NUM         Number of executors to launch (Default: 2).
                              If dynamic allocation is enabled, the initial number of
                              executors will be at least NUM.
```

That explains why it worked when you switched to YARN. It is supposed to work with YARN (regardless of the deploy mode, i.e. client or cluster which is about the driver alone not executors).

You may be wondering why it did not work with the master defined in your code then. The reason is that it is too late since the master has already been assigned on launch time when you started the application using spark-submit. That's exactly the reason why you should not specify deployment environment-specific properties in the code as:

1. It may not always work (see the case with master)
2. It requires that a code has to be recompiled every configuration change (and makes it a bit unwieldy)

That's why you should be always using `spark-submit` to submit your Spark applications (unless you've got reasons not to, but then you'd know why and could explain it with ease).

Answer (score 7):

If you’d like to run the **same application** with **different masters or different amounts of memory**. Spark allows you to do that with an default `SparkConf`. As **you are mentioning properties to `SparkConf`, those takes highest precedence for application**, Check the properties precedence at the end.

**Example:**

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
```

Then, you can supply configuration values at runtime:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --name "My app" \
  --deploy-mode "client" \
  --conf spark.ui.port=56487 \
  --conf spark.master=yarn \ #alternate to --master
  --conf spark.executor.memory=4g \ #alternate to --executor-memory
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
  --class WC.WordCount \
  /<myjar>.jar \
  /public/blahblahblah \
  /user/blahblah
```

---

> **Properties precedence order (top one is more)**
>
> 1. Properties set directly on the `SparkConf`(in the code) take highest
>      precedence.
> 2. Any values specified as flags or **in the properties file** will be passed
>      on to the application and **merged** with those specified through
>      **SparkConf**.
> 3. then flags passed to `spark-submit` or `spark-shell` like `--master` etc
> 4. then options in the `spark-defaults.conf` file.
>
> A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.

Source: [Dynamically Loading Spark Properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties)